# Script to automatically open SQL Server Management Studio 2005 from another interface

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

Please I need help with a script that can help me open the SQL Server Management Studio 2005 from a button in an another interface.

Thanks Roger

Comment: What language is the other interface written in?

Comment: BTW There are very few, perhaps none, reasons why an application would open SSMS programatically. Almost all of the SSMS functionality is covered by SMO (since SSMS runs on top of SMO). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx

Comment: I am designing an interface for querying data in sql server 2005. the data is imported from Active Directory. I would like at a click of button on the interface to open the sql studio.

Answer (score 2):

sqlwb.exe is SSMS in SQL Server 2005 and it has parameters such as -S etc for Server name, but also has a filename parameter.

At command prompt, run sqlwb /? to get command line usage

Answer (score 1):

With C#:

```
using System; 
using System.Diagnostics;

void StartStudio() 
{
      Process proc = new Process();
      proc.StartInfo.FileName = "ssms";
      proc.Start(); 
}
```

Comment: Filename = ssms. Really? reference please

Comment: @gbn: Default SS2008 location is: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\Ssms.exe`

Comment: I'm sorry, we actually talk about 2008, the question is about 2005