# Script to automatically open SQL Server Management Studio 2005 from another interface

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssms

Please I need help with a script that can help me open the SQL Server Management Studio 2005 from a button in an another interface.

Thanks Roger

Comment: What script/button/interface?

Comment: exact duplicate of question #1353863

Comment: possible duplicate of [Script to automatically open SQL Server Management Studio 2005 from another interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353863/script-to-automatically-open-sql-server-management-studio-2005-from-another-inter)

Answer (score 0):

look at the link

[Script to automatically open SQL Server Management Studio 2005 from another interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353863/script-to-automatically-open-sql-server-management-studio-2005-from-another-inter)